# jQuery $(document).click conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive website. There are two functions: nested functions are used in both, handling event `$(document).click()`. Both hide the same elements — `.dropdown.slide-out`. However, in the first case, the function refers to the selector `.dropdown`, and in the second case to the selector `.slide-out.` The first works only: where am I going wrong?

```
/*
    |---------------------------------------
    | Dropdowns
    |---------------------------------------
    */
$(function () {
    var label = $('.dropdown-toggle');
    var allDropDowns = $('.dropdown-menu, .rmb-popup');
    var el = $(this);
    label.click(function () {
        if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 768px)')) {
            allDropDowns.hide();
            $(this).parents('.dropdown').children('.dropdown-menu').toggle('fast');
            label.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false
        }
    });

    // Conflict point #1. Hide .dropdown.slide-out-right
    $(document).click(function () {
        allDropDowns.hide();
        label.removeClass('active');
    });

    allDropDowns.click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

```
/*
    |---------------------------------------
    | Slide-outs
    |---------------------------------------
    */

$(function () {
    var soRight = $('.slide-out-right');
    $('.btn-menu-secd').click(function () {
        if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 767px)')) {
            soRight.animate({
                right: 0
            }, 400)
        }
        return false
    });

    // Conflict point #2. Slide out .dropdown.slide-out-right
    $(document).click(function () {
        if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 767px)')) {
            if (soRight.attr('style')) {
                soRight.animate({
                    right: '-270px'
                }, 400, function () {
                    soRight.removeAttr('style')
                })
            }
        }
    });

    soRight.click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: why ? 'Both hide the same elements — .dropdown' ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're having.  Can you describe what type of click works an what type of click doesn't work?  You do realize that you've assigned two separate behaviors to a click in the document, right?

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: @samitha, I wanna to hide, for example <div class="dropdown slide-out-right"> clicking outside of it. But in the first case I want to do this with the hide effect, and the second with the slide-out effect.

Comment: @jfriend00, I just a marketer and designer w/ some front-end development skills. Maybe, I don't realize problem w/ 2 separate behaviors :)

Comment: @Franciso I am now on the road. I can do a JSFiddle  later. May be suitable for clarity test server?

http://fxc.nickysheen.ru/
http://fxc.nickysheen.ru/a/js/scripts.js

However, a page in Russian, if you are not scared. The problem in the languages switcher ​​in the upper right corner. If you reduce the browser window, open languages menu and try to click beyond, you will see that menu hides and does not slide out as intended.

(Thanks God 4 Google Translator :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:** I was wrong. JQuery starts from 1.7 let to attach more than one or more handlers on 1 event. It will execute it in order of binding [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cBaN5/)

1:

```
$(function(){
var allDropDowns = $('.dropdown-menu');
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        allDropDowns.show();
        return false;
});
$(document).click(function() {   
    allDropDowns.hide();
});    
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
});
});
```

2:

```
$(function() {
var slideOut = $('.slideout');
$('.btn-menu').click(function() {
        slideOut.show();
        return false;
});
$(document).click(function() {
    slideOut.hide();
});
$('.slideout').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: thanks. But this decision, in my opinion, would complicate the structure of the code. Is there a way to isolate the event handlers, maybe? In plug-ins they do not conflict with other code, right?

I've experimented with a namespace, .on/.off, local variables, but to no avail.